# How to add a full path to the PATH variable using Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, path

How do you add a full path to the PATH variable using Bash?
I've tried for example somthing like

```
export PATH=/myPath:$PATH
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: This is fine, where did you do this export?

Comment: on the command line using my Linux machine.

Comment: ok and what exactly is not working after that export?

Comment: so there's a program on my computer that checks whether this path was added to the PATH variable or not and apparently it's stating that it's not.

Answer (score 1):

The `export` command only takes effect in the current shell, for all programs started subsequently to that `export` command.

To make it take effect for other shells, and after you logout, you'll need to add the command to your `~/.bashrc` file and restart the other terminal windows/tabs.

To make it take effect for GUI applications when they are not started directly or indirectly from a terminal window, an additional step *may* be required.

To make it take effect for applications running as another user (e.g. root), a different additional step may be required.

Answer (score 0):

The code you mentioned above works perfectly well: PATH variable gets changed - for current bash session and all processes started from it.

The source of the problem is probably the following:

Your program gets a copy of environment variables on it's start. If environment variable (PATH or anything else) is changed after the program start, the program will not "see" the change. You'll need to restart a program.